# Query users from different azure tenant

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

We have a case where we have 'clients'. Every client is an different Azure tenant but we keep their tenant id in the database. So we have Angular application where we want to have like a dropdown with all the clients and based on the selected client to query their tenant users so we can add him to our database and give them permissions and stuff to all other applications. As per my readings this in not achievable, 
[image]

Because this permission application will be used from like 3-4 guys which are part of our tenant only.

Is there a way we can achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use the [`User.Read.All` Application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0) and authenticate using the [Client Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?toc=./ref/toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0) grant. You would then need to retrieve a token from each tenant prior to calling `/v1.0/users`.

Note that this will require receiving Admin Consent from each tenant you need to query.

---

Rohit's comment below is an excellent point. If your app is a SPA, meaning the authorization is happening entirely in the browser via Javascript, you're really limited to the OAuth's [Implicit Grant](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-implicit-grant/).

To use [Client Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?toc=./ref/toc.json&view=graph-rest-1.0) or [Authorization Code](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/) grants, you need some kind of backend API to handle the authentication and calls to authenticated APIs. I would argue that you should be doing this anyway, if for no other reason than forcing your user to reauthenticate every hour isn't a great user experience.

If you don't mind requiring each user in the tenant to authenticate, you could use the Authorization Code grant. This is a bit more complex of a set up because it requires you to keep track of separate Refresh Tokens for each user. Your backend would need to retrieve the Refresh Token, Exchange it for a set of new tokens (`access_token` and `refresh_token`), Store the new Refresh Token, and then call the API using the new Access Token.

Since there is a 1:1 relationship between the Token and the User so, at scale, you're looking at a lot of tokens. You'll also need a bunch of maintenance workflows to handle issues that may come up (refreshing the token fails, new scope requirements, etc.).

It really comes down to the depth of the relationship between your app and the tenant. If you're providing security and analysis to the entire organization, then asking for global `Mail.Read` is certainly reasonable. If you're providing a service to just part of an organization, it can be hard to get IT to sign off on such a broad permission scope.

Comment: Just want to add.. @Denisx Client Credentials Grant is meant only for confidential clients and since you mentioned `Angular application` in your question, if it's an SPA that runs in client browser, you can't use this grant in angular application code directly. You may need to use a backend API that supports your angular application and uses client credentials grant (as confidential client).

Comment: Hmm thanks, does that mean I'll have to have client secret from every tenant or one only from my app registration? Also this sounds a bit too much as well while we need the `oid` only. Maybe as a workournd I can make little app where the user would be redirected to register in our database if he has no permission and in this app I was talking about someone can have give permissions to the users who requested that. Sounds good?

Comment: You only need a single App ID and Secret. Also, @RohitSaigal is spot on, you'd want this done on your backend. I'd argue that you'd want to do that regardless since it's a) more secure and b) easier on your users. I'll update my answer with some details on your other question.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur So basically, We'll have to register new application in our tenant which will be our backend API for example. Create the secret and stuff and store them somewhere in our config etc. Also Give this API the mentioned permission. Our FE based on the selected client it will send the `tenantId` to this backend and this backend will get the token and get the users and return the users to the FE. But how does the client tenant will give consent to use? I mean when we require token our app Id will get automatically registered somewhere in the client tenant or ?

Comment: Consent is actually the easy part (assuming they're willing to give it of course). It's basically just a link you provide to their Admin. They sign in, say "yup" and you're done. Take a look at for https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/ for an overview.

Comment: This seems ok for me. Anyway if they don't provide consent we won't be able to provide our product. I don't think they have much options. Of course this will be probably mentioned in the contract, but its out of my scope. I'm just a developer :) Thanks for the help !

Comment: Isn't that the truth. We're all "just a developer" until something fails at 3am. ;)

Comment: Hi again, I have 2 tenants (using my 2 gmail accounts). Just to clarify I'm using v1. In the first one I've registered the app as native, created secret and gave the `User.Read.All` application permission. Now I'm trying to get the users from tenant 2. Created the api for getting the token and I get `Application with id xxxx was not found in directory xxxx`. I guess this is because of no admin consent. However when requesting `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?client_id=xxxx` I get redirected back to selecting account without any error.

Comment: You cannot get admin consent from `/common`. You need to use the tenant URI (i.e. `https://login.microsoftonline.com/mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/adminconsent?client_id=xxxx`)

Comment: Still no success. If I replace [mydomain-xxxx] with tenant 2 I get the `Application not found in directory` If I use tenant 1 I get error that the user has to be added as external user.

Comment: If you're using v1, you need to make sure you've configured it to be multi-tenant.

Comment: Ufff, that worked. Thank you very much, I wish you all the best :)